# MySQL data has wrong encoding when displaying using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I am absolutely stuck.

I have an old website that was running on PHP4 and MySQL4. The SQL data contains slovak special characters (á, š, ť, ľ, ž etc.). The old site displays the characters fine.

I've migrated the site to a new host, it is now running on PHP 7.3 and MariaDB 10.3. I have replaced deprecated mysql_ functions with MySQLi and now the code runs fine. However, the characters are completely messed up.

I've came across multiple questions and answers, here's what I've tried:

1. Setting charset to utf8 and/or windows-1250 to mysqli connection

   `$link->set_charset("utf8mb4");
   mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, "utf8");`
2. Setting both utf8 and/or windows-1250 headers to every .php file

   `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`
3. Re-saving each file manually with UTF8 and/or windows-1250 encoding using Sublime text
4. Changing database collation to utf8_unicode_ci, utf8_slovak_ci and also something else
5. Altering character sets of all tables and database

   `ALTER DATABASE databasename CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
   ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;`
6. Manually converting the output from UTF8 to windows-1250 using PHP's iconv (this messed up the output even more)

   `$output = iconv( "Windows-1250", "UTF-8", ($output));`
7. Tried different collations when importing the old database. Also tried with and without MYSQL40 import compatibility mode in phpMyAdmin
8. Setting both utf8 and/or windows-1250 html meta charsets

   `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1250">
   <meta charset="UTF-8">`

Something that I've discovered. When I read the SQL data directly in phpMyAdmin, it displays the exact same data with messed up encoding in both old database (mysql4) and a new one. However, the old site somehow displays it correctly on the front-end.

I am really stuck, I really think I've tried every solution. What might be the problem?

Comment: Have you tried deleting a row/adding a new row with the same letters? Maybe the table rows messed up when the server updated. You could also try making a new database and see if the formatting is messed up on that one as well.

Comment: can you tell what should be displayed and what its displaying now?

Comment: give your  table  create query with some insert data

Comment: or attach table so that we can see whats going

Comment: To help debug:  `SELECT HEX(col), col FROM ...`  to see what is in the table.

Comment: "completely messed up" -- Which of these cases is it?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Comments by [sbondo1234](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11025032/sbondo1234) and [Tausif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7088390/tausif) helped me to realize that the new records work just fine. Only the old data in the database is messed up. It was easier for me to create a simple matrix and pair incorrectly encoded characters with correct ones and then update them with simple SQL queries. Thanks for your help.